# db2jcc4.jar throws UnsupportedCharsetException when querying through DBeaver

Tags: database, jdbc, db2, dbeaver

I have a DB2/zOS database that I need to access. When I create the connection on DBeaver it tests fine and when I open the connection it lets me browse schemas and tables.

The top stacktrace gives a generic SQLError, but I think the culprit is a `java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: Cp280`.

I'm pretty sure it's a query problem (as opposed to a ResultSet problem) because even if I type gibberish in the query it throws the same exception.

I think it's a problem with my particular machine as trying it on my coworker's PC it goes through without a itch. We use the same version of DBeaver, the same connection, the same VPN and the same drivers. I've already tried updating my `db2jcc4.jar` to the latest 10.1 release, remaking the connection (although with the same settings) and rebooting my PC.

Would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Check the operating system locale settings on your machine and your coworker's machine to see if they are different, e.g., one set to `Italian (Italy)` and the other set to `English (United Kingdom)`.

Comment: Hi Gord, unfortunately I can't check right now, but I tried changing mine to `English (US)` and `English (UK)` and I was still getting the same error. I'll report back on Monday about that. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thanks to Gord for trying to help, unfortunately it seemed like it was a DBeaver bug that was fixed in version 6.1.2, which came out yesterday. It works fine now.